# Using Apache Cordova Can I p2p file sharing

Tags: apache, cordova, p2p, file-transfer

Can I use Apache Cordova p2p file sharing. File Transfer is able to send and receive files over the server with Plugin. But I do not want to do over the server. Source can search about it (eg application or website), you can tell.
My ability to make file sharing in this way do you have any.

Answer (score 0):

Either build a plugin using android documentation, or you can use something like `http://peerjs.com/` directly in Cordova.